# Running Virtuoso Interactive SQL query via HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, virtuoso, isql, openlink-virtuoso

I want to know if it is possible to run an isql query via HTTP in OpenLink Virtuoso.

I understand that the isql server runs on port 1111, but I cannot find any example (e.g. curl) to run an SQL query (not SPARQL) via HTTP.

I don't want to use ODBC because that would require configuration on different environments (UNIX or Windows) and I don't have time to change our Vagrant scripts for that.

JDBC is also not an option because we run on NodeJS and that would require a wrapper that would put additional overhead on the query times.

Running OpenLink Virtuoso 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data service at `1111` is not an HTTP service, so `curl` cannot be used against it.

You may be able to script something to run against the HTTP-accessible iSQL implementation at <`http://{{virtuoso-host:port}}/conductor/isql.vspx`>. Note that this is digest-auth protected and was intended for human interaction, so the client tool may need to parse the HTML of the response.

If that won't serve your needs, I suggest you ask on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/).  There are likely other options.

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was thinking... hacking something to use the conductor is out of the question, too much hassle and brittle code. It should be possible to send the commands via JDBC, but I also cannot get it to work behind the node-jdbc wrapper... I am stuck with the HTTP requests, which start failing after some thousand queries...  Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489180/closing-openlink-virtuoso-http-connections